# SQL want to ask about Select clause

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery

I have this SQL statement:

```
select max(avrg) 
from (select sum(points) as avrg 
      from marks 
      group by num_eleve) s;
```

I had problems making it work and turns out that I needed the `s` at the very end, without it the statement fails.

I want to understand what the `s` does, In other words, why does the above work while the following fails?

```
select max(avrg) 
from (select sum(points) as avrg 
      from marks 
      group by num_eleve);
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS? MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc?

Comment: i'm simply using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(avrg) 
from (select sum(points) as avrg 
      from marks 
      group by num_eleve) s;
```

In the above query `s` is alias name to the `sub-select`

```
(select sum(points) as avrg from marks group by num_eleve)
```

It will be used to refer the columns present in `Sub-select`. Your query can be written as

```
select max(s.avrg)  --here I have added s.avrg 
from (select sum(points) as avrg 
      from marks 
      group by num_eleve) s;
```

Also if you want to join the sub-select with another table which has column named `avrg` then to differentiate from which table you want `avrg` column value   `s` will be used

```
select max(s.avrg)  --here I have added s.avrg to pull valued from sub-select not from another_table 
from (select sum(points) as avrg 
      from marks  
      group by num_eleve) s Left join another_table b on s.avrg = b.avrg
```

Comment: Which standard requires it?

Comment: I guess except Oracle every RDBMS needs it

Comment: Seems 1992 requires it:  https://blog.jooq.org/2014/06/24/should-i-put-that-table-alias-or-not/

Comment: I'm pretty sure earlier versions of MySQL did not require it.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of your query:

```
(select sum(points) as avrg from marks group by num_eleve)
```

is acting as a table, and simply needs a name.  The "s" will do, but it can be anything.  You could call it MyTable or Averages or Mxyzptlk if you want.